# How do I put a backround image with url?

Tags: html, css, image, url, background-image

I am new to programming, I have a picture I just edited and I have to put it as the background of my html, the teacher gave us the next to complete:

```
body {
  background-image: url (" ");
}
```

I am not sure if I have to complete that with a link or with the name of a picture I have in my compuer, but neither work.

Comment: Did you do any research? What, specifically, did you try? When you say “*neither [worked]*” what went wrong, were there any errors reported?

Answer (score 0):

Check the extension of the image, I think its case sensitive. Try

```
    body { 
  background-image: url("your-image.correctExtension");
}
```

Comment: Why? What problem does it fix? What does it mean? (Yes, I know all of that, but look at the question, and teach the OP so s/he can learn.)

Comment: you can replace the url with the path to your local image

Comment: Please add any explanations to the answer, not the comments.